# php pdo + mssql returning weird stuff

Tags: php, sql

I have installed `php5-sybase` as a driver for mssql (to use `pdo dblib driver`)

In my sql database I have a field filled with NEWID() ( like this : `E28AC04B-035B-4F59-A5DD-EC3E2D738FA7`) but when I use php pdo (prepare + execute + fetch) to receive this value , it returns : `Ü¶!YÉ/G¸/çiç:w PuTTY`) . Everything works but only this field looks like crap.

Any ideea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noone answers I started to mix things and to search microsoft documents and I was able to figure it out :

The query has to have CAST on that field like so :

```
SELECT CAST(id as varchar(255)) as id ...
```

and it will work with no problems, but you cannot use `SELECT *` as that field needs to be selected separte

Comment: sorry ... I did not see the language I wrote the answer :) tired